# Hosting WCF service through Console

Tags: .net, wcf

I created a WCF service and Hosted it through console. but when I created another Web Application and tried to add it service reference its give error

> Metadata contains a reference that
>   cannot be resolved:
>   'net.tcp://192.0.0.0:9100/ConsoleApplication3/Communicator.svc/mextcp'.
>   Could not connect to
>   net.tcp://192.0.0.0:9100/ConsoleApplication3/Communicator.svc/mextcp.
>   The connection attempt lasted for a
>   time span of 00:00:00.9843750. TCP
>   error code 10061: No connection could
>   be made because the target machine
>   actively refused it 192.0.0.0:9100. 
>   No connection could be made because
>   the target machine actively refused it
>   192.0.0.0:9100 If the service is defined in the current solution, try
>   building the solution and adding the
>   service reference again.

Here is code:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Communicator)))
            {
                host.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to terminate the Host application.");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
 }

[ServiceContract]
public interface ICommunicator
{
    [OperationContract]
    string SayHello();
}

public class Communicator : ICommunicator
{
    public string SayHello()
    {
        return "I am here";
    }
}
```

And here is the configuration:

```
    <configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="ConsoleApplication3.Communicator" behaviorConfiguration="CommunicatorBehavior">
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <endpoint address="ConsoleApplication3" binding="netTcpBinding"
            contract="ConsoleApplication3.ICommunicator"/>
        <!-- This Endpoint is used for genertaing the proxy for the client -->
        <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and
       remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
        <endpoint address="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexTcpBinding" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9100/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="CommunicatorBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you got a wrong address to try and get at your service.

You have hosted a service yourself in a console app, with `netTcpBinding`, and you've defined a base address of `net.tcp://localhost:9100/`, and the MEx endpoint is at `net.tcp://localhost:9100/mex`.

So you need to use either the base address

```
net.tcp://localhost:9100/
```

or the MEX address

```
net.tcp://localhost:9100/mex
```

when trying to connect to the service.

I don't know how you came up with this address (`net.tcp://192.0.0.0:9100/ConsoleApplication3/Communicator.svc/mextcp`) that you seem to try to connect to - but this address is **not** valid. First of all - there's no *.svc file to be used when self-hosting a `netTcpBinding` webservice, and I don't know where you got this `/mextcp` address from.....

**Update:** I took your code, created a new console app with the interface and service implementation and your service config, and it works just fine on my machine:

[image]

I did get a warning from Windows Firewall when I tried to launch the console app from within Visual Studio about allowing access - which I did allow.

Comment: So what should be the Address I tried 'net.tcp://localhost:9100/mex
' but still the same errror

Comment: @BreakHead: or this one, that seems to be the one you're ultimately going to:  `net.tcp://192.168.168.145:9100/`

Comment: @Breakhead: in that case, something else must be causing issues... some kind of a TCP/IP setup - a firewall maybe? Can you turn off **all** firewalls and stuff like that just for a test?

Comment: I turned off the Firewall stilll the same error, can you do a favor and can try the code at ur end??

Comment: @BreakHead: your code and config are fine - works like a charm on my machine. There must be something else getting in your way here.....